# Azure Pipelines fails in Deployment Slots

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created my release pipeline with few stages (DEV, QA, Production) where the Production App Service has a Deployment Slot with Auto Swap Enabled. However when I perform the release, it fails in the swapping slot tasks with the below error message. Have gone through many articles available in google and stack overflow but doesn't seem to help. Any pointers on what could be wrong would be very much helpful.

```
2021-08-18T16:30:41.0295503Z ##[error]Error: Failed to swap App Service 'jdmessaging' slots - 'preprod' and 'production'. Error: Conflict - Cannot modify this site because another operation is in progress. Details: Id: 32473596-226d-46b4-9c98-31285c27418e, OperationName: SwapSiteSlots, CreatedTime: 8/18/2021 4:28:43 PM, WebSystemName: WebSites, SubscriptionName: 74d83097-e9c9-4ca7-9915-7498a429def4, WebspaceName: DEMO-CentralUSwebspace, SiteName: jdmessaging, SlotName: preprod, ServerFarmName: , GeoOperationId: (null) (CODE: 409)
```

Note: For the first time, the release happened successfully with Deployment Slots. However, now we are trying the second release and encountered this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems like more of the scenario,

1. One Operation triggered was yet to complete, meanwhile another operation was trigged on the same site (site modification)
2. Second operation was waiting for first operation to complete on the same and ultimately the second operation failed

**Suggestion:**

1. Wait for sometime and re-try the operation. It should succeed.
2. If still failed, please create a technical support ticker by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) where technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.